# Java reading txt.file - access denied?

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception, readfile

I have created a `txt` file which I have saved in *My Documents* on my computer.  I am trying to read the `txt` file through `FileReader` and `BufferedReader`.  However, when I try to run the program I get the error message:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: <filelocation> (Access is denied)
```

Does anyone know what causes this, and how I might fix the problem?  I have tried saving the document other places too, but I always get this message.  I am sure the file path is correclty entered.

Comment: I think that exception tell everything "FileNotFoundException". Can You show the code plz?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281143/java-io-filenotfoundexception-access-is-denied

Comment: Can you add the relevant code of where you are accessing the file? Your exception message is also missing some info (ie. the file name) ... can you add the full stack trace as well?

Comment: Thank you for the comments.  As far as the entire error message goes, it is as follows:  Error upon reading: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Kristian\Documents (Access is denied).  Most of my code is not written in English, however, so I would need some time if you wish for me to put up the code in its entirety.  I can perhaps try some of the methods suggested in the link provided by G_H

Comment: Do you close the stream properly after reading? "C:\Users\Kristian\Documents (Access is denied)" looks like you have problems with the spaces in the path. Please post the line where the file name is created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One random guess is that you may be having multiple instance of your test program running so the file is locked by earlier instance of your program which is still running. You can check open consoles in the eclipse or you can restart eclipse.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  This actually helped!  The only thing now is that I get something a bit mystifying in the outprint.  My outprint says:   " ï»¿Student 20: 30.4
Student 19: 87.6
Student 21: 91.34"   However, the symbols ï»¿ are not meant to appear.  What could cause this?

Comment: It may be that your file is having some character that the eclipse console does not support. You can configure the encoding for the console in run-as dialog. Can you update the question with the contents of file and the program incase the problem persists.

Comment: Hi.  Thanks again.  I tried opening the file in a different Eclipse program which I also use for reading textfiles, and here everything runs smoothly.  Thus, since I am now able to run the file properly here, I think I will just leave it at that.  I really appreciate your help though!

Answer (score 12):

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Kristian\Documents (Access is denied)

You are trying to read a directory, not a .txt file.

Comment: This was also my issue. Why can't they just say "folder was specified instead of file"???

Answer (score 0):

there could be 2 types of issue.

1. your path is containing space in folder or file name. you can solve
   it by using the non-8dot3 file name by using the command `dir /p /x`
   in command prompt of that folder path.
2. you can save the form in your project folder and use relative path `./txt.file`. if you have the file under a path say `<project folder>/input/txt.file`, your relative path will be `./input/txt.file`. If this doesn't work try googling the code for file reading and you will find out your mistake.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Appreciate your tips.  Together with the help above, I am now able to run this properly in one of my Eclipse programs.

Comment: @EJP Please find justification for my answer 

    File file = new File("./ src/CollectionUtils.java");
    System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath() + file.isFile());

    File file1 = new File("./src/CollectionUtils.java");
    System.out.println(file1.getAbsolutePath() + file1.isFile());

**sample output **
/Users/nbabu/workspace/FunProject/./ src/CollectionUtils.javafalse
/Users/nbabu/workspace/FunProject/./src/CollectionUtils.javatrue

Comment: @NaveenBabu What answer? Neither of the points in your answer identifies the actual problem, and the mess of code in your comment remains unexplained.

Answer (score -1):

Could be that you have to change the security settings on your folder. Go into the directory, right click  properties, select Security , advances and change permission so that all child dependencies inherit the security changes.