# FileNotFoundException when using FileWriter

Tags: java

I am trying to write some message to text file. The text file is in the server path. I am able to read content from that file. But i am unable to write content to that file. I am getting FileNotFoundException: \wastServer\apps\LogPath\message.txt (Access Denied).

Note: File has a read and write permissions.

But where i am doing wrong. Please find my code below.

Code:

```
    String FilePath = "\\\\wastServer\\apps\\LogPath\\message.txt";

    try {
        File fo = new File(FilePath);
        FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(fo); 
        BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(fw); 
        bw.write("Hello World"); 
        bw.flush(); 
        bw.close(); 
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Please help me on this?

Comment: What platform is this running on?

Comment: @theunlucky: how do you know this to be a fact? To Ranganath: please print the entire stack trace.

Comment: Is the file open by another process?  You `try-catch` is dangerous as it's not actually attempting to close the file should a write file (even though the file was opened)

Comment: [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281143/javaio-filenotfoundexception-access-is-denied)

Comment: Java platform. Sample java class to write some content into that file. File is on WAS logs server path.

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \\wastServer\apps\LogPath\message.txt (Access is denied.)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:190)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:142)
 at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:84)
 at FileCheck.main(FileCheck.java:15)

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether you can access the `apps` and `LogPath` directory.

Type these on Run (Windows Key + R)

```
\\\\wastServer\\apps\\

\\\\wastServer\\apps\\LogPath\\
```

And see whether you can access those directories from the machine and user you are executing the above code.

Comment: I have a access for all directories.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have write access to the share, one of the directories, or the file itself. Possibly the file is already open.

Comment: I checked the fileExists and canWrite permissions. Both are true.

Answer (score -1):

After this line

```
 File fo = new File(FilePath);
```

try to print the absolute path

```
System.out.println( fo.getAbsolutePath() );
```

And then check whether the file exists in that location, instead of directly checking at

```
\\\\wastServer\\apps\\LogPath\\message.txt
```

So , you will know, where the compiler is searching for the file.

Comment: It's already an absolute path. The file doesn't have to exist in that location. The compiler isn't searching for the file. Nobody is searching for the file.  His program is destructively opening the file for output. Not an answer.