# java.io.FileNotFoundException: G:\uploads (Access is denied) while uploading images using servlet in Java

Tags: java, servlets, filenotfoundexception

> java.io.IOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: G:\uploads (Access is denied)
>       com.efashion.controller.ProductController.doPost(ProductController.java:52)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
>       org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    for (Part part : request.getParts()) {
        String fileName = extractFileName(part);
        String fieldName = part.getName();
        if(fieldName.equalsIgnoreCase("file2")||fieldName.equalsIgnoreCase("file1")){
            part.write(Utils.UPLOAD_DIRECTORY + File.separator + fileName);

        }
        //part.write(fileName);
    }
    request.getRequestDispatcher("viewproduct.jsp").forward(request, response);
}

private String extractFileName(Part part) {
    String contentDisp = part.getHeader("content-disposition");
    String[] items = contentDisp.split(";");
    for (String s : items) {
        if (s.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
            System.out.println(s.substring(s.indexOf("=") + 2, s.length()-1));
            return s.substring(s.indexOf("=") + 2, s.length()-1);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: The implied question: " why am I getting this error?"  I'm guessing that Utils.UPLOAD_DIRECTORY is "g:\uploads" in which case the server is not running with high enough permissions to write to that directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FileNotFoundException when using FileWriter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596861/filenotfoundexception-when-using-filewriter)

Comment: You can try with a java program, a simple main java programa that write a file to that directory. You have to run the program with the same user that you run de appserver.

Comment: @Thevenin  Thanx mate.!!!  Finally it did worked. I had 2 input type file where I only uploaded 1 file but after I upload both the file it did worked.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, when I was sending multiple file upload but when some files are missing it throws FileNotFoundException (Access Denied). So I added required attributes to all upload fields and it works. Files uploaded successfully.