# Creating and Writing to a File

Tags: java, file

```
if (!file.exists())
  file.mkdirs();
  file.createNewFile();
```

The error states that I have a problem with actually 'writing' Go Falcons to the file, it will state that the file access is denied, Does that mean something is wrong with my code?

Error states: FileNotFoundException
Access is denied

PS: how do I actually read this file, once it's writable?

Comment: `FileWrite extends Exception` ?? Perhaps you need to start with something simpler than file IO...

Comment: Please always tag your question with the language you're using. I've added `java` this time.

Comment: Check access permission for this file. Also, take a look on related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281143/java-io-filenotfoundexception-access-is-denied.

Comment: Very sorry for not tagging it correctly

Comment: @user3788930 A hint for future programs, is that instead of printing an exception with `System.out.println()`, it is better to run the `printStackTrace()` method on the exception object itself.  This gives you much more information about how and why your program is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, one approach would be to use a [`PrintWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  File outFile = new File(System.getenv("HOME") // <-- or "C:/" for Windows.
      + "/hello.txt");
  try {
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(outFile);
    pw.println("Go Falcons");
    pw.close();
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Which creates a single line ascii file in my home folder named "hello.txt".

```
$ cat hello.txt
Go Falcons
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
if (!file.exists())
  file.mkdirs();
  file.createNewFile();
```

To:

```
if (!file.exists()) {
  file.createNewFile();
}
```

But first, go read some tutorials or articles. Why are you extending `Exception`?

Comment: My teacher said something about "Every program I do from now on in class needs exceptions" Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: You should double check what your teachers about their expectations first

Comment: @user3788930 Yes, you are doing it wrong.  You teacher was referring to the fact that you need to handle exceptions (catch or re-throw them), not suggesting that all of your classes extend the `Exception` class.  Look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) to learn more about how to handle exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that right before you attempt to create your output file, you first create a directory with the same name:

```
            if (!file.exists())
                file.mkdirs();      // creates a new directory
            file.createNewFile();   // fails to create a new file
```

Once you've already created the directory, you can no longer create the file, and of course, you cannot open a directory and write data to it as if it were a file, so you get an access denied error.

Just delete the `file.mkdirs();` line and your code will work fine:

```
        if (!file.exists())
            file.createNewFile();   // creates a new file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take the substring of the path till folder structure(excluding file name) and create directories using method **mkdirs()**. Then create file using **createNewFile()** method. After that write to newly created file. Don't forget to handle exceptions.