# (CSVWriter) java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\output.csv (Access is denied)

Tags: java, eclipse, csv

I am using the CSVWriter from [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-csv-file/)

```
String csv_path = "C:\\output.csv";
CSVWriter csv_writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(csv_path));
csv_writer.writeAll(data);
csv_writer.close();
```

But I encounter the common exception of `Access is denied`

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\output.csv (Access is denied)
```

I found an [accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281143/java-io-filenotfoundexception-access-is-denied), but it seems cant solve my problem since I am using `FileWriter`.

> You cannot open and read a directory, use the isFile() and
>   isDirectory() methods to distinguish between files and folders. You
>   can get the contents of folders using the list() and listFiles()
>   methods (for filenames and Files respectively) you can also specify a
>   filter that selects a subset of files listed.

I am using window 8. Is it something to do with the permission issue?

Comment: I seem to recall windowses not liking writing directly to root (unless you're admin). Try another directory instead (such as user's home dir).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the eclipse as Administrator

Answer (score 2):

The user running the java program probably does not have access to C:\

I would check the read/write permissions of the user under which you run the program.
Alternatively, you can try a different dir not located at the root of your C drive.

Answer (score 0):

Open Windows Explorer, under c: drive, right click your mouse to check whether there's option to create a file . You may compare the menu when you right click your mouse under other folder.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I inadvertently tried to open the parent directory with the **FileWriter** instead of the actual file. It's a common gotcha so I'll post this in case it reminds somebody else to check the obvious.